# Using org.eclipse.core.resources with RAP

Tags: eclipse-rap

I am currently trying to port an Eclipse RCP plugin to RAP (it is my first experience with RAP). I had a look at several sample applications and tutorials on how to port, but all information I have got says that the bundle `org.eclipse.core.resources` should be available (as long as I don't misinterpret them completely).

I have resolved all other Required-Bundle-errors, but '`Bundle 'org.eclipse.core.resources' cannot be resolved`' resides. It seems that `org.eclipse.core.resources` is not included with the RAP target platform (I installed it via Eclipse and checked the settings).

Is `org.eclipse.core.resources` not included anymore and if yes, what can I use to replace it? Or how can I include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle `org.eclipse.core.resources` is not part of the RAP target platform, and it never was. The original bundle the Eclipse platform is not suitable for RAP.

To use the resources bundle with RAP, a RAP version would have to be created, that provides per-session workspaces in `ResourcePlugin#getWorkspace()`. It's technically feasible but probably a fair amount of work.

Comment: Is this available now ? I am working on workbench application and I need these to create IResources with Wizards. Can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: @ralfstx : Could you please let me know how to add org.eclipse.core.resources for RAP.